# Both VPS and domain changed but Database URL stayed the same and PHPmyadmin inaccessible to change it

Tags: database

As I'm new to Linux and WPCLI, I moved a site from one VPS to another but URL stayed the same and PHPmyadmin doesn't work so as of the moment I can't change the site URL from PHPmyadmin.

When I try to navigate to the site from the browser (after setting up a database, changing wp-config.php accordingly, uploading site dir with right permissions etc) I get a 500 error.

I ten went did `sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` and saw an error regarding that site, but with the old url (so somewhere the url wasn't changed and this seems to be the source of the problem). This is the error:

> [Sun May 07 15:20:21.881125 2017] [:error] [pid 19110] [client
>   IP_ADDRESS:56239] PHP Fatal error:
>
> Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/contentperhour.com/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0

I thought it's Wordfence related so I tried to remove it:

```
sudo wp plugin deactivate wordfence
sudo wp plugin uninstall wordfence
```

Removing Wordfence and restarting the server didn't help.

How could I change the URL of the site from outside the site or outside PHPmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site and home URLs aren't serialized, if you access to the database export, you can change them directly in that file with a text editor.

You can also override the database values temporarily in `wp-config.php` with some `define`s:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear: I can't access the DB file of my site from PHPmyadmin (and don't know a way to do so without PHPmyadmin) so I need to run some search and replace from within the Linux CLI.

Comment: Then editing `wp-config.php` is probably the easiest. You can then update the values in the database with `update_option`, see [Changing The Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more info.

Comment: Hi Milo, I thumbed up your answer. I tried to use the define method you presented but it seems not to be enough and I still need to change the domain somewhere else in the DB (can this be?)...

Comment: what are the current symptoms? the error you have above isn't related to URL, it's the internal path to the file on the server.

Comment: The site doesn't go up, it shows a 500 error on the browser, yet everything seems to be in place. The dir name in document root, the DB and DB user names, the wp-config file, everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the solution by Milo but if you want to do so from Bash, you could querying MySQL directly from it (note the comments):

```
mysql -u root -p # Start Bash querying mode and Proceed to DB of choice.
    use wordpress; # Delete "wordpress" and put your WP DB.
    show tables;
        update wp_options set option_value = 'http://correctDomain.name' where option_id = 1;
            select * from wp_options where option_value = 'http://www.correctDomain.name';
                \q # Quit querying mode.
```

- The [original article](https://blog.khophi.co/change-wordpress-site-url-via-command-line-mysql/) includes a Cname (www.) in the update and select queries but I removed it here.
- Make sure to disable any "defines" you might have added to wp-config.php.